# Why does the redirect to page 404 in MODX not work?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources

I have correctly configured the resource id in the "site" section in the system settings. But when I enter a mysite/ non-existentaddress in the browser, instead of a redirect to 404, a redirect to the main page occurs

I tried to add in my htacceess file redirect to 404, but it didn’t help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your `error_page` system setting has published resource ID as desired 404 page, right?
What do you see here https://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php checking yoursite/non-existentaddress URL?

This setting should work without any htaccess additions, please comment them if any.

BTW how about friendly URLs, is it active now?

Comment: Thank you Anton! This is the second time you have answered my questions.
When I checked the main page, it said "CONGRATULATIONS. Everything seems to be fine."
When I checked the non-existent URL, it was written again: "CONGRATULATIONS. Everything seems to be fine." and a sentence was added in the line below: the non-existent url I entered, 404 not founded.
I was very surprised that you asked about friendly urls. I have made all the necessary settings, but despite this, the friendly urls don’t work: the page url looks like this: http://my_domain/index.php?id=1

Comment: Do you have default .htaccess file? Otherwise some strings may be absent/commented out and FURLs don't work. Btw what web server do you use? This may be helpful: https://docs.modx.com/2.x/en/getting-started/friendly-urls

Comment: great news, please mark answer as solution!